# Vim ~ Cobol Problems

Tags: linux, vim, cobol

I am using a gnu / linux system

When I open a Cobol file with Vim :

vim xxx.cbl

my vim key mappings just reset to normal I dont know why, I can't work like that.

but if I open any text data with any extension like .c or .cpp or .txt

Everything is ok.

here is my .vimrc :

```
set autoindent                                                     │
set cindent                                                        │
                                                                   │
inoremap <Esc> <Tab>                                               │
inoremap <Tab> <Esc>`^                                             │
                                                                   │
map <C-c> :w <CR> :!gcc % -o %< -lpthread && ./%< <CR>             │
map <C-P> :w <CR> :!clear;perl %<CR>                               │
                                                                   │
map <C-x> :w <CR>:!clear;python3 %<CR>                             │
                                                                   │
map <C-k> :w <CR> :!cobc % -free % -x % -o %<  && ./%< <CR>        │
                                                                   │
let cobol_legacy_code=1                                            │
                                                                   │
                                                                   │
                                                                   │
set expandtab           " enter spaces when tab is pressed         │
set textwidth=120       " break lines when line length increases   │
set tabstop=4           " use 4 spaces to represent tab            │
set softtabstop=4                                                  │
set shiftwidth=4        " number of spaces to use for auto indent  │
set autoindent                                                     │
syntax on                                                          │
                                                                   │
filetype plugin indent on                                          │
                                                                   │
execute pathogen#infect()
```

Please help.
What could be the Reason ?

Comment: Is that your complete vimrc?

Comment: Dont ever remap Esc. It breaks things.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going to have to trace through any plugins triggered by filetype .cbl.

An easy start might be the `:scriptnames` command.

```
prompt$ vim normal.txt
:scriptnames
```

Either try and remember the lists, or in a different terminal window...

```
prompt$ vim file.cbl
:scriptnames
```

Scroll to the bottom of the minibuffers for the scriptnames lists. Visually compare to find which of the last few files sourced by Vim might be different.  Start looking through .cbl triggered Vim scripts for any undesirables.  A guess is that it'll be in an autoloaded cobol.vim file, where ever it may happen to be first found.  :scriptnames lists complete pathnames.